# pynput and pydirectinput mouse movements are innacurate unless pyautogui is imported

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui, pynput

I am trying to simulate holding down a mouse and moving it to a list of specific coordinates before releasing. I've found that pyautogui's move and drag functions don't work over multiple movements but pydirectinput does.

However, when I use pydirectinput.moveTo(), it moves it to coordinates that are ~125 pixels off.
This fixes itself when I import pyautogui.

With this code:

```
import pydirectinput
pydirectinput.moveTo(500, 500)

import pyautogui
print(pyautogui.position())  # where it moved before importing
pydirectinput.moveTo(500, 500)
print(pyautogui.position())  # where it moved after
```

I get the output

```
Point(x=625, y=625)
Point(x=500, y=500)
```

I get the same output with pynput using

```
from pynput import mouse
m_control = mouse.Controller()
m_control.position = (500, 500)

import pyautogui
print(pyautogui.position())  # where it moved before importing
m_control.position = (500, 500)
print(pyautogui.position())  # where it moved after
```

What could be causing this and how would I go about fixing it?

**Edit:**
I figured out that this is because of dpi scaling (I'm on windows 10). The default scaling on my computer is 125%. Multiplying everything by 1.25 solved the issue.